# SSH login and /tmp on 100%

Tags: ssh

Not counting the reserved space by root (usually 5%), if the /tmp is really 100% full, so 0 bytes free, **why couldn't we log in to the machine via ssh**? We only got the error message "cannot fork".

Are there any parameters to the ssh client so that we could still log in to a machine when it has a 100% full /tmp?

UPDATE: reboot is not really an option :\

Comment: You should include output of df as well as vmstat -s (memory condition).

Comment: Have you checked all the logs in your system?? BTW, what is the os, version, and distribution you are talking about?

Comment: If you can't access the machine nor reboot it, I'm afraid there's not quite much to do. Investigating `/tmp` and `ps -ef` would be a great idea. With such an issue, your machine's services are very likely to go down anyway, which eventually makes the rebooting scenario quite enjoyable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the full `/tmp` is the problem. The `fork()` system call only fails with that specific error if there are too many processes running.

Do you have a ulimit set?

If you can't access the console, then there's very little you can do...

Answer (score 1):

On many systems, `/tmp` is a virtual file system that lives on RAM. Depending on how you're configured, filling it up may eat up all your RAM and leave you without enough memory to initialize a new process.

As you can imagine, that's not something that `ssh` can work around after the fact. But you can prevent it from happening in the future by tuning `/tmp` so that it can't grow quite this large.

Comment: In this case the error message would be `fork: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: You may be right. But we don't know what OS we're talking about so I wouldn't rule this out yet.

Comment: You're right of course, I somehow had taken this for a Linux system, but we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen cases where /tmp is backed by SWAP space....so if you are swapping AND have a lot of /tmp activity it is very possible that running out of SWAP space you would see this message.

If you are out of memory, then you may have very little choice than to reboot.  The memory killer may be working, however, it indiscriminately kills off processes of which some might be important.

Another thing is that one (or more) processes have filled up the process table.  With no more slots available, you can get that message as well.  Your solution here would be a search and destroy operation on the processes causing the condition....assuming you can login.  If you cannot login, then reboot is your only alternative.

Finally, of course, the machine software or hardware might be having a serious problem.  Thus causing the situation you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

A process failing to fork is because either the system is out of memory or because the user has hit their maximum number of processes - because of, for example, a fork bomb.

I'm curious how you know that /tmp is full if you can't log into the machine - but my guess would be that whatever process has filled up /tmp may also be sucking up the resources needed for you to ssh in.

If you have physical access to the machine, you could try using a console login to get things back to a usable state, or use magic sysreq (assuming it's a Linux machine) to get things under control.

You may also be able to get sftp working even when ssh won't, since it ought to use less memory and fork fewer times than a shell - and you can use it to delete files from the remote, if you can get logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try ssh after a reboot. Once I encountered similar problem which was resolved automatically after a system reboot!

Comment: many thanks, but updated the question!

Comment: Then you could check the etc/sshd_config or /etc/ssh/sshd_config and increase the MaxStartups. Then restart ssh service.

Comment: User can't access the machine at all...